# Create loop to create PostgreSQL columns

Tags: sql, excel, postgresql, loops, csv

I have a dataset of 320 columns in a csv file where the header is simply the number of trip.

Each column represents a trip, a route of street names from A to B. 
(It was a simple list, that I transposed in excel to create the trip numbers as heads.)

I would like to import it to a postgreSQL table.

I saw previous similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27298759/adding-multiple-columns-via-a-loop-in-postgresql), but as it's only 320, I wonder if that is the best structure and if yes how to loop the column creation in order to insert the data through pgAdmin.

I figured so far this, that returns error message:

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN 
FOR i IN 1..320 LOOP
   INSERT INTO runs (col_i, col_id) -- use col names
   SELECT i, id
   FROM   tbl;
END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a table with 320 `text` columns:

```
DO
$$BEGIN
EXECUTE (
   SELECT 'CREATE TABLE my_tbl (c'
        || string_agg(g::text, ' text, c')
        || ' text)'
   FROM generate_series(1,320) g);
END$$;
```

A sane relational design might be (wild guess, there's not nearly enough information):

```
CREATE TABLE street (
  street_id serial PRIMARY KEY
, street    text NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE trip (
  trip_id  serial PRIMARY KEY
, whatever text
);

CREATE TABLE trip_step (
  trip_id   int REFERENCES trip
, step      int
, street_id int NOT NULL REFERENCES street
, PRIMARY KEY (trip_id, step)
);
```

Consider:

- [How to implement a many-to-many relationship in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789736/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-postgresql/9790225#9790225)

Comment: But a table with that many columns is typically a big misunderstanding. Are you sure you didn't mean 320 *rows* consisting of 2 columns or something?

Comment: Thanks Erwin. 
Maybe I should have a different data structure. what would you suggest? 
These are all street names, so same data type, but each column represents a separate route.

Comment: @Peter: There's not enough information, I can only guess. See update. For anything more I suggest you start a new question about the design, where you provide all the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your datatype max number of columns go from 250 to 1600, so that may be a problem

[What is the maximum number of columns in a PostgreSQL select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12606842/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-columns-in-a-postgresql-select-query)

If you already have your data in excel, you can use save as CSV and use `COPY` to import the data

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2987451/3470178

OR use string concatenation to create INSERT statmente in excel.

Comment: I did try the copy but it returns error:
ERROR: extra data after last expected column
SQL state: 22P04
Context: COPY runs, line 1: "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,3..."

I assume because there is no column identified yet? I created table "runs" but no columns. 

My data is simple text, with first line header can be INT.

Comment: Peter try to create a small sample with 10 columns to make sure the problem isnt the number of columns and validate you have proper sintaxis. If still get sintaxis error you need to provide a full example so we can help. And you need create the columns on the csv the link i give you say how.

Comment: Juan, I successfully imported 3 columns when I created the columns beforehand. 
So the question returns: how can I create 320 columns as a loop so that I can import the csv?

Comment: Are the column names some kind of sequence? why not just create the columns by hand if the table exists using `ALTER TABLE distributors ADD COLUMN address varchar(30);`. If the table doesnt exist the link i provide will create the columns for you if the csv has a header.